# why leaf nodes connected each other in clustered index?

Tags: sql-server

As we know,when an clustered index is created,it is index key data is stored in a B-tree structure.The Bottom level of B-tree are the leaf nodes which  contains the actual data rows for a table, and all leaf nodes point to the 
next and previous leaf nodes.I want to know the purpose  of using double linked list to connect leaf nodes.
I will be appreciate to any answer to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know the purpose of using double linked list to connect leaf
>   nodes.

It is an efficient way to fetch the data ordered forward or backward when doing range queries.

Ex:

```
select ID
from YourTable
where ID between 10 and 20
order by ID desc
```

With an index on ID the above query can do an index seek on `20` and scan the index backwards to `ID = 10` returning all rows found.

Comment: Is there are any other benefits to demonstrate the mechanism

Comment: @RebornXu : "efficiency" is not being understated here. It is a pretty big benefit considering that without it SQL Server would have to re-traverse the tree every time it was done with a page and wanted to find the next one. Also think about doing a `SELECT TOP (200)` query, or a query that needs to scan other, non-indexed fields.

Comment: @RebornXu i think this example pretty much sums it up. There are of course a lot of other queries that benefit but it all boils down to scanning a range of the index. Equality with a non unique key is one, joining two rather large tables with a merge join is another since the input has to be sorted for the merge join operator.